# Database table gets updated twice when a request to download occurs

Tags: php, mysql, download

I have a project where my users will be able to download a file (pdf,docs,txt,images etc.). So I am providing a link to download like this-

```
<li><a href="home.php?search=<?php echo $search_string; ?>&search_submit=Search&page=<?php echo $page; ?>&download=<?php echo $result_materialsID; ?>">
                                            Download</a></li>
```

Then I check in my $_GET method I check a condition like this-

```
if(isset($_GET['download']))
{
    $material_to_download = $_GET['download'];
    $result_update_materials = mysqli_query($connection,"Update Materials SET numDownload=(numDownload+1) where materialsID = {$_GET['download']}");
    if(!$result_update_materials)
    {
        die("Database update numDownload materials failed:".mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    $result_get_materials_l = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT downloadLink FROM Materials where materialsID = {$_GET['download']}");
    if(!$result_get_materials_l)
    {
        die("Database get materials failed:".mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    else
    {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_materials_l))
        {

            download_file($row[0]);
        }

    }

}
```

It is under a nested ifs where I checked other $_GET variables. The function download_file is given below:

```
function download_file($file)
{
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);

    }
}
```

**Problem:**  The problem is, when I click on a download link, the file downloads fine, and as the code goes, my database should increment numDownload by 1. But it increments by 2. numDownload is keeping track of the total number of downloads of that file. So I think that the update part of my code is actually running twice.

I tried `unset($_GET['download'])` but it didn't help. Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried no brackets....I can't see that being the problem, but I would try it like numDownlaod = numDownload+1

Comment: For starters, You should probably use a prepared statement instead of directly putting the GET['download'] variable into the query. It makes you vulnerable. Trying to find your error now. :)

Comment: And are you only expecting one row back?? Cuz why are you doing a fetch_array with a loop? instead of just a fetch_row?

Comment: I think the error has to be surrounding the if(isset($_GET['download')..We might need more code. That code looks like it should increment fine

Comment: Tried with braces around numDownload+1 , that didn't help. And expecting one row because the query is done on a primary key.